# I want to make a list of images in ARKit but I can't return it

Tags: swift, arkit

I have made the list with the help of someone else but I need to return the node and it says "ERROR use of unresolved identifier node."

This is the code:

```
func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode? {
    let arrayOfImages = ["Photo1", "Photo2", "Photo3", "Photo4", "Photo5", "Photo6", "Photo7", "Photo8", "Photo9", "Photo10", "Photo11", "Photo12", "Photo13", "Photo14", "Photo15", "Photo16", "Photo17", "Photo18", "Photo19", "Photo20", "Photo21", "Photo22", "Photo23", "Photo24", "Photo25", "Photo26", "Photo27", "Photo28", "Photo29", "Photo30"]
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayOfImages.count)))
    let Image = UIImage(named: arrayOfImages[randomIndex])
    let Texture = SKTexture(image: Image!)
    let Sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture:Texture)
return node               //ERROR use of unresolved identifier node.
}
```

I will be very grateful If anyone could help me out.

Comment: That's better. So what do you think `node` is? You need to specify an actual variable that exists in your code.

Comment: Ok so what should I do

Comment: Which variable in that method represents the `SKNode` you need to return?

Comment: the function view

Comment: Huh? Your `view` method needs to return a value with a type of `SKNode`. Now look at your code inside your `view` method. Which variable represents an `SKNode`? Return that variable. And in case it isn't clear, I know the answer. I'm trying to get you to think it through yourself to come up with the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure, but is it the SKSpriteNode in the Sprite var?

Comment: Exactly. Use `return Sprite`. BTW - It is standard practice to named methods and variables starting with lowercase letters. Class, struct, and protocol names start with uppercase letters.

Comment: Thanks so much. Most people just tell you the answer but thanks for making me work it out because now I know what to do next time.

Comment: You can answer your own question and explain the mistake you made. It would help others facing similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode? {
    let arrayOfImages = ["Photo1", "Photo2", "Photo3", "Photo4", "Photo5", "Photo6", "Photo7", "Photo8", "Photo9", "Photo10", "Photo11", "Photo12", "Photo13", "Photo14", "Photo15", "Photo16", "Photo17", "Photo18", "Photo19", "Photo20", "Photo21", "Photo22", "Photo23", "Photo24", "Photo25", "Photo26", "Photo27", "Photo28", "Photo29", "Photo30"]
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayOfImages.count)))
    let Image = UIImage(named: arrayOfImages[randomIndex])
    let Texture = SKTexture(image: Image!)
    let Sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture:Texture)
    return Sprite // because it is SKSpriteNode.
}
```